# Run a bash script when new file directory?

Tags: python, linux, bash

So I have a folder on linux server where files are uploaded. However these files (mp3) need to be altered automatically once they have been uploaded.

For example I have found a python module which can modify the tags in mp3 files within a folder. However this module and the specific tag related command needs to be executed when a new file is uploaded..automatically.

Is this something that a bash script would be capable of achieving and if so what is needed to achieve this? I have read about inotify and similar but am still unsure if this is the best method.

Any input would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) facilities, e.g. thru [`incron`](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en). As the [documentation](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=doc&lang=en) of `incron` explains, you probably want

```
 /your/directory IN_CLOSE_WRITE /path/to/my_script.sh $@/$#
```

as an `incron`  job entry.

Comment: Link-only answers are pretty useless. Plus ``inotify`` is pretty low-level. At least [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) is a pretty nice wrapper and toolkit.

Comment: I disagree. Knowing the *name* of the `incron` package is useful. The link is only to help.

Comment: I take it back :) Never come across ``incron`` before. Nice one.

Comment: Thanks guys will check out incron

Answer (score 1):

What you are after is something like [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog)

From their examples you can use `watchdog`'s command-line tool like this:

```
watchmedo shell-command \
    --patterns="*.mp3" \
    --recursive \
    --command='/path/to/my_script.sh "${watch_src_path}"' \
    .
```

Comment: to help you in your googling: bear in mind he is not referring to the linux watchdog daemon. he is talking about [this python program](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog)

Comment: Sorry I forgot the link :)

Comment: Thanks will check out watchdog..for python